# Make use of 3 dataframe columns to create a dictionary with Col1 as Key and a dictionary of (Col2 and col3) as values for that Col1 key

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

everyone. I really need some help regarding a dictionary that I want to create using the following dataframe (as an example).

| Column1 | Column2 | Integer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Orange | 5 |
| Apple | Pineapple | 10 |
| Apple | Juice | 3 |
| Strawberry | Raspberry | 11 |

I want this dataframe be converted into a dictionary like that:

- first column to be a key with a dictionary as value (with column2 as key and integer as value)

The output should be:

```
dictionary = {
'Apple': {'Orange': 5, 'Pineapple': 10, 'Juice': 3}
'Strawberry': {'Raspberry': 11}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `Column1` and create key value pairs inside a dict comprehension

```
{k: dict(zip(g['Column2'], g['Integer'])) for k, g in df.groupby('Column1')}
```

---

```
{'Apple': {'Juice': 3, 'Orange': 5, 'Pineapple': 10},
 'Strawberry': {'Raspberry': 11}}
```